# Get dir Folder Name and Only Upto 2 Subfolders Name

Tags: vba, excel, directory, subdirectory

I want to get Names of Folders from a Directory and Names of Any Subfolders from that Directory Upto 2 Levels.

So It's Main Dir -> Folder Name -> SubFolder1 -> SubFolder2

The code below gets all the Folders and Subfolders Name.I got the code from [here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2219-excel-list-all-folders-and-subfolders.html) . Any idea how can I limit to just two subfolders only ?

```
Option Explicit

Sub FolderNames()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xPath As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object, j As Long, folder1 As Object
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the folder"
    .Show
End With
On Error Resume Next
xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
xWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = xPath
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array("Path", "Dir", "Name", "Date Created", "Date Last Modified")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder1 = fso.getFolder(xPath)
getSubFolder folder1
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).Interior.Color = 65535
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object)
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim subfld As Object
Dim xRow As Long
For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
    xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(SubFolder.Path, Left(SubFolder.Path, InStrRev(SubFolder.Path, "\")), SubFolder.Name, SubFolder.DateCreated, SubFolder.DateLastModified)
Next SubFolder
For Each subfld In prntfld.SubFolders
    getSubFolder subfld
Next subfld
End Sub
```

Comment: So you cherry picked a solution and ask us to amend it for your goal? where is your effort? please share with us what have you tried already and why that doesn't work?

Comment: That code is complete overkill and very slow for iterating through subfolders. But in answer to your question - why not just run the code you've got and filter the results for anything with 4 "`\`" or less?

Comment: @MacroMan That's a very good idea. I will try to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSubFolder is implemented a little bit strange ... but you can simply add a second parameter - let's call it Level as integer to it. When calling the procedure from the Main Dir you can set it to 0. In the recursiv call within the procedure you add always 1 to it before you pass it. So you know always at which level you are

```
Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object, ByVal Level As Integer)
    Dim SubFolder As Object
    Dim subfld As Object
    Dim xRow As Long

    Level = Level + 1
    If Level >= 3 Then Exit Sub

    For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
        xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
        Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(SubFolder.Path, Left(SubFolder.Path, InStrRev(SubFolder.Path, "\")), SubFolder.Name, SubFolder.DateCreated, SubFolder.DateLastModified)

        getSubFolder SubFolder, Level

    Next SubFolder

End Sub
```

haven't tested, but should work.

here the same code with the If statement inside the loop:

```
Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object, ByVal Level As Integer)
    Dim SubFolder As Object
    Dim subfld As Object
    Dim xRow As Long

    Level = Level + 1

    For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
        xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
        Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(SubFolder.Path, Left(SubFolder.Path, InStrRev(SubFolder.Path, "\")), SubFolder.Name, SubFolder.DateCreated, SubFolder.DateLastModified)
        If Level <= 2 Then getSubFolder SubFolder, Level

    Next SubFolder

End Sub
```

The result should be the same.

Comment: Shouldn't the If statement should be inside For Loop ?

Comment: you can also put it inside but then with the call of getSubFolder instead of Exit Sub ...but then you have to change the If criteria as well

Comment: Tried it it says Argument not optional :/ in the main Sub when it calls the getSubFolder folder1

Comment: as I said: you have to pass 0 as Level when calling from the Main Dir

Comment: sorry ... there was an error in the code above ... the increase of the Level has to be outside the loop. Fixed that in the code

Comment: Okay It ran but returned only the name of First Folder just One from Selected Dir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96295/discussion-between-cboden-and-rohan-k).

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue whereby I wanted to stop looping through other subfolder once I got the folder I wanted using the FolderExists function. However as I used a For loop to loop through subfolders of FileSystemObject and as VBA does not allow you to get out of the For loop like you do to a While loop, I used Exit Sub statement after returning the desired sub folder by using the  = retval statement format.